# Confusion while Sending Notification in Android

Tags: android, notifications, retention

I am trying to send push notification through the following code.
**Problem**: I want to send push notification to users after two days.

In MainClass

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationReciever.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*2, pendingIntent);
```

The Reciever Class is

```
public class NotificationReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    showNotification(context);

}


private void showNotification(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stubMain

    PackageManager pm = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    ApplicationInfo ai;
    try {
        ai = pm.getApplicationInfo( context.getPackageName(), 0);
    } catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
        ai = null;
    }
    final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle(applicationName)
    .setContentText("We haven't seen you in a while. Play now");
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
}
```

}

**Confusions:** When I run this code, the notification is sent immediately and after two days too. I don't to send the notification immediately  I only want to send it after two days again and again.
Secondly do I have to call the above code every time the user starts the app or I have to call it once only? Or I have to call it after two days? I want to send the notification every two days as long as the app is installed.

Please guide me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setRepeating` method 2nd parameter suggests when the first alarm should go off. You have specified it as `System.currentTimeMillis()`, hence it goes off immediately.

Change:

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*2, pendingIntent);
```

to

```
long updateInterval = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*2;
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + updateInterval, updateInterval, pendingIntent);
```

Regarding your 2nd question

> Secondly do I have to call the above code every time the user starts
>   the app or I have to call it once only? Or I have to call it after two
>   days? I want to send the notification every two days as long as the
>   app is installed.

You will have to call it once. The notification will shown every two days until the app is uninstalled.

You can register a `BroadcastReceiver` for intent [android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH), which will be sent out the first time your application is launched. Here you can set the repeating alarm. May be you need to handle [android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED), in case a newer version of your app is installed.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) bounty will be awarded in 22 Hours.

Comment: Bounty has been awarded thanks for your help.
One thing more I want to know is that if I have sent the call to send notification after 2 days. How can I pause the notifications?